# Sort contents in content list

Tags: nodes

I need to sort contents in the same manner as blocks are sorting in the block list.
In the block list we can drag an drop blocks to place the them up and down, same functionality I needed for content list for contents.

Answer (score 1):

To add *Sort* functionality using *Drag and Drop* into `admin/content` section, you need to play with administration views using [Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module. Note that [Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/weight) module is also necessary for this. After installing and enabling these module you can *edit* administrative views under `admin/views` section.

But if you simply want to add your new views of specific contents then there is already *Weight* view available under `admin/views` section. You can check this view to see the working and functionality using *Drag and Drop*.

Note: Weight module must be enabled for contents to be sorted.